# How should I transfer variables/ parameters securely between multiple domains in PHP?

Tags: php, session, variables, parameter-passing, url-parameters

I would like to securely transfer sensitive variables between multiple in PHP. Normally I would use url parameters or session cookies to transfer non-sensitive values. I'm not sure how secure I can make cookies and url params or if there is a better option out there?

Comment: Are the domains common to each other? sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, etc..? If that's the case, you can set the cookie on the parent domain and it'd be visible to all the sub domains. If the domains are completely different, then you'd have to use url parameters, and some form of encryption for the security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need good security, you can `serialize()` your parameters into a string, and AES encrypt the string on the origin server with `mcrypt()`, wrapped in base 64 encoding with `base64_encode()`.  Pass the encrypted, encoded data to the other server as a single URL parameter where it can be decrypted using the AES shared key and parsed back to individual variables with `unserialize()`.